# How to detect rectangles with rounded corners more accurately

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to create a program that will take a long time to explain here, so I'm gonna tell you guys the part that I need help with.

Here I need to detect a rectangle(which will be a license plate in our example). It does the recognition almost perfectly but I want it more precise. Here is the example image I used.

[image: plate]

As you can see, It does a fairly good job at finding it but I want to take the rounded corners into consideration too.

Here is the source code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils

def find_edges(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(image=gray, threshold1=100, threshold2=200)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]
    for c in cnts:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
        if len(approx) == 4:
            screenCnt = approx
            break
    return screenCnt


image = cv2.imread('img/plate.jpeg')
cnt = find_edges(image)
cv2.drawContours(image, [cnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('Outline', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Is there any way that I can achieve this and how so, or am I tryharding too much on this?

[image: sample]

**Edit:** Adding sample image. Sorry for not including before, my fault.

Comment: You already have a nice approximation of the outline. You can sample the image along short segment perpendicular to the sides, and detect the transitions from white to black (or from blue to black). This will give you more accurate points that you can join with fitted lines.

Comment: @fmw42 Added sample image.

Comment: You can also try Hough lines in ROIs adjusted around the edges.

Comment: From the contour you want, get the rotated rectangle. See cv2.minAreaRect() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9

Comment: Are you trying to get the black outer plate holder? If so, why? Why not just get the white rectangle surrounding the numbers?

Comment: @fmw42 I need to get the plate size by pixels. Considering that I know the focal length and the original plate size, I'll calculate the distance between the camera and the plate.

Comment: Car plates come in different sizes, so what is the point trying to be accurate ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust In my country there is exact 2 different sizes when it comes to car plates.

Comment: Even between normalized plates there are differences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, in your `find_edges` function, I replaced the line `screenCnt = approx` with `screenCnt = c`, in order to keep all the coordinates in the resulting detected contour:

```
def find_edges(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(image=gray, threshold1=100, threshold2=200)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]
    for c in cnts:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
        if len(approx) == 4:
            screenCnt = c
            break
    return screenCnt
```

Then, I defined a function, `get_opposites`, that will take in a contour, and return two coordinates from the contour that are farthest apart from each others:

```
def get_opposites(cnt):
    current_max = 0
    c = None
    for a, b in combinations(cnt, 2):
        current_distance = np.linalg.norm(a - b)
        if current_distance > current_max:
           current_max = current_distance
           c = a, b
    return c
```

Next, I separate the contour detected from the image *(using the `find_edges` function you defined + my alteration)* into two part; the first part containing the top-left + bottom-right quarter of the contour, and the second part containing the top-right + bottom-left quarter of the contour:

```
image = cv2.imread('img/plate.jpeg')
cnt = find_edges(image)
xs = cnt[..., 0]
ys = cnt[..., 1]
x_mid = (np.amin(xs) + np.amax(xs)) // 2
y_mid = (np.amin(ys) + np.amax(ys)) // 2
tl_br = cnt[((ys < y_mid) & (xs < x_mid)) | ((ys > y_mid) & (xs > x_mid))]
tr_bl = cnt[((ys > y_mid) & (xs < x_mid)) | ((ys < y_mid) & (xs > x_mid))]
```

Finally, I use the `` function to get two coordinates from each part, and place them into a numpy array to be drawn onto the image:

```
p1, p3 = get_opposites(tl_br)
p2, p4 = get_opposites(tr_bl)
cv2.polylines(image, np.array([[p1, p2, p3, p4]], np.int32), True, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('Outline', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:

[image]

All together:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils
from itertools import combinations
       
def find_edges(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(image=gray, threshold1=100, threshold2=200)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]
    for c in cnts:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
        if len(approx) == 4:
            screenCnt = c
            break
    return screenCnt

def get_opposites(cnt):
    current_max = 0
    c = None
    for a, b in combinations(cnt, 2):
        current_distance = np.linalg.norm(a - b)
        if current_distance > current_max:
           current_max = current_distance
           c = a, b
    return c

image = cv2.imread('img/plate.jpeg')
cnt = find_edges(image)
xs = cnt[..., 0]
ys = cnt[..., 1]
x_mid = (np.amin(xs) + np.amax(xs)) // 2
y_mid = (np.amin(ys) + np.amax(ys)) // 2
tl_br = cnt[((ys < y_mid) & (xs < x_mid)) | ((ys > y_mid) & (xs > x_mid))]
tr_bl = cnt[((ys > y_mid) & (xs < x_mid)) | ((ys < y_mid) & (xs > x_mid))]

p1, p3 = get_opposites(tl_br)
p2, p4 = get_opposites(tr_bl)
cv2.polylines(image, np.array([[p1, p2, p3, p4]], np.int32), True, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('Outline', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Clear and nice explanation too, thanks!

Comment: @Onur My pleasure!